# Is there a CSS shorthand to write a rule that overrides a property for multiple classes if they are descendants of a specific class?

Tags: css

I have rules established for multiple classes that are sometimes descendants of an element with a specific class that will override some properties:

I can write a list of classes sharing a property like this:

```
.normal, .other {property x, property y}
```

With non shared rules for each class specified separately:

```
.other {property z}
.normal {property w}
```

I can write an override for a single nested class like this:

```
.top .normal{override property x}
```

I can write a multiple override like this:

```
.top .normal, .top .other {override property x}
```

But is there a shorthand way of writing that? I have a long list of classes, with names a lot longer than .top to override, and no, I'm not able to change the HTML structure or main CSS definitions.

Something like .top [.other, .normal]{override property x} would be ideal.

```
<div class="top">
<div class="normal">Nested normal</div>
<div class="other">Nested other</div>
</div>
<div class="normal">Normal</div>
<div class="other">Other</div>
```

Comment: In plain CSS it is not possible, you should take a look at SCSS, SASS, LESS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using some of dynamic stylesheet language like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). It allows you to make nested classes. Example:

```
.top {
  .normal {
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  .other {
    font-weight: 700;
  }

}
```

Will compile to:

```
.top .normal {font-weight: 400;} .top .other {font-weight: 700;}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not an option for us.

Answer (score 0):

In a plain **css** file you can't do what you ask for. You will need a css pre-compiler (SASS, LESS), which I highly recommend to use.

So you'll be able to do something like this:

```
.top {
   .normal{
      color: red;
   }
   .other {
      color: blue;
   }
}
```

If you can't use a css pre-compiler for whatever reason, then you should give a try to this sass to css converter [sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/).

For more info about the SASS pre-compiler, you can look into the [SASS official page](http://sass-lang.com/)